# Correct way of using ngif with mat-cell

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

All I'm trying to do is display a certain value if the item has a certain property, but all I end up with is `[object Object]`. This is my approach.

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Given Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
      <div *ngIf="item.hasOwnProperty('value'); else default">
          // Display something else
      </div> 
      <ng-template #default>
        {{item.name}}
      </ng-template>
    </td> 
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write `*ngIf="item.value"` if the property is mandatory for the item that should have it.

Else, if the `value` property is present even when it is not filled (Which should not happen btw), then you could edit your items with a boolean in your .ts file, something like :

```
ngOnInit() {
  // To do before to set the data in your table
  this.data = this.data.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    hasValueProp: item.hasOwnProperty('value'),
  }));
}
```

then in your html template you'll condition it like:

`*ngIf="item.hasValueProp"`

Comment: Yes, that works. But the problem I'm still having is that placing a `div` or other element inside `<td mat-cell>` causes it to be displayed as [object Object]

Comment: Well can you provide a repro of your problem then please ? `[object Object]` is linked to the shape of the data you are trying to display, we need to know it to help you.